# JQUERY JSON AJAX works offline but not online

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I got this code. It works absolutely fine on my localhost but when I put it online it only saves the data to the database but it doesn't seem load it.

When I pass a string from the api.php to the site via ajax it works. So maybe it has to do with json. On the other hand I was trying out the get_json example from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ on my server and that does work as well.

I tried out many different things like jsonp, json-fallback and so on but nothing seems to work.

This is the code:

api.php:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
$tableName = $_GET['page'];
$category = $_GET['category'];
$date = $_GET['date'];

if ($date == Null){
if ($category <> Null){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE category LIKE '$category'");  
}else {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName"); 
}
}else{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE date LIKE '$date'"); 
}

$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

somewhere in the backend:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'api.php?page=home', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows) {                        
        for (var i in rows){
                var row = rows[i];  
                var vdate = row[0];
                var vtitle = row[1];
                var vcontent = row[2];
                $('#edate').val(vdate);
                $('#etitle').val(vtitle);
               $('#econtent').val(vcontent);
            }
    }
});
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Any errors in your web server log ? or php errors ? or mysql errors ? or errors in the browser ?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't examine this in great detail but this is probably your problem:

```
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

you should close that while and also json encode the $row and not $data

Answer (score 0):

Check your console (firefox or chrome press `F12` > Click `Console`, See any errors?, post them to your question.

Also use the `$.ajax` built in error handler.

```
$.ajax({  
url: 'api.php?page=home',
data: "",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(rows) {
    for (var i in rows){
            var row = rows[i];  
            var vdate = row[0];
            var vtitle = row[1];
            var vcontent = row[2];
            $('#edate').val(vdate);
            $('#etitle').val(vtitle);
           $('#econtent').val(vcontent);
        }
},
// Any HTTP Errors will be alerted.
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
}
});
```

**Mainly**.. Check your console for errors. It must be throwing an error in your console, or the handler above.

Comment: ah thanks for your quick replies. I just uploaded it to a different server and now it works... well.. :)